# How to simulate the synthetic data for 2 pole low pass filter for Kalman application?

Tags: kalman-filters

I was trying to simulate data for a 2 pole low pass filter inorder to solve with kalman filter to estimate the true states. With the below code I was unable to generate true states that look like sin function. I took x(t) = A0sin(wc*t) with wc = 2*pi*fc, fc is cutoff frequency. Can some one help me regarding this?

I am trying to simulate a sinosoid and here how the result looks:
[image: result of code]

The simulated data of state space model does not look like a sinsoid (x(t)).
Can someone guide if I am looking the result worng way?

```
F =

    1.0000    0.0001
   -0.0012    1.0000

eig(F)

ans =

   1.0000 + 0.0004i
   1.0000 - 0.0004i
```

The state space model looks like

\begin{eqnarray}
 X_k &=& F X_{k-1}+ q_k \nonumber \\
 Z_k &=& H X_k + \nu_k
\end{eqnarray}

```
clear all; close all; clc;

% Define the parameters
A0 = 1;
fc = 0.5;
w = 2*pi*fc;

% Define the continuous-time state-space representation
A = [0, 1; -w^2, 0];


H = [1, 0];

% Convert the continuous-time state-space representation to a discrete-time state-space representation
fs = 8192;
Ts = 1/fs;
F = expm(A*Ts);

% Preallocate the arrays for the state and the measurements
N = 3*fs;
x_array = zeros(2,N);
z_array = zeros(1,N);

VarMnoise = 0.15;
vk = (sqrt(VarMnoise)*randn(N,2)); 


VarqNoise =0.25; % Variance of Q (proportinal to height of A0);
qk = (sqrt(VarqNoise)*randn(N,1)); 

% Initialize the state
x = [0; 0];

% Generate the measurements
for k = 1:N
    x = F*x + qk(k,:);
    z = H*x + vk(k);
    
    % Store the state and the measurements
    x_array(:,k) = x;
    z_array(k) = z;
end

% Plot the results
t = Ts*(0:N-1);
figure;
plot(t, x_array(1,:), 'LineWidth', 2);
hold on;
plot(t, z_array, 'LineWidth', 2);
legend('State', 'Measurements');
xlabel('Time (s)');
ylabel('Value');
```

Comment: "I was unable to" -- **how**?  Please _edit your question_ with the plots that you _did_ generate, and tell us how what you see doesn't match what you expect.  Printing out your calculated $\mathbf F$ and it's eigenvalues would be useful, too.

Comment: Hi @TimWescott, I edited the quesiton and updated with plots. I am expecting to simulate a sinsoid that looks like x(t) = sin(w0*t). But the plots looks too vague. Or I might be interpreting things a wrong way fro the plots.

Comment: Are you after generating Sine like signal using a linear state model like in Linear Kalman?

Answer (score 0):

You have a zero-damping (hopefully) harmonic oscillator with a noise input, starting with both states equal to zero.  It's period is two seconds and you're only simulating it for three seconds.  Try giving it a run time of at least 20 seconds (10 periods) -- that should give you some opportunity to see something interesting.

Note that because it's an undamped oscillator fed with noise, it's amplitude will be the absolute value of a random walk function.

Finally, you're *probably* just exceeding the precision of your output, but you may want to check that abs(eig(F)) - 1 is very close to zero, and isn't positive.  It's almost a doesn't-care because it's a nonstationary process with, ultimately, an infinite variance, but there is a difference between a random walk and a slowly growing exponential, at least eventually.